# Как вписать img в div (автомасштаб и подгонка) CSS

Tags: html, php, css

Вон как у вконтакте сделано, тоесть имеем БЛОК, и имеем кучу картинок 100х300 200х500 500х250 тоесть разномастных. Как сделать это на css? возможно? я нашел только такое решение на javascript но хотелось бы средствами css.

Вон как на большинстве магазинов превьюшки красивые маленькие и хоп они четко вписываются в блоки... или это надо каждый раз картинку php резать?

посоветуйте хорошее решение, если нельзя чисто на css, спасибо!

Comment: Приведите пример кода что у вас не получается. в вопрос добавьте.

Comment: Думаю автор имеет ввиду как сделать что то вроде этого, но на CSS: 

http://ilyaut.ru/addons/gallery-in-the-style-of-vk-or-yandex-kartinki/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это называется **адаптивная верстка**

```
  /* От ландшафтного экрана телефона до потретного планшета */
  @media (max-width: 767px) {

  }

  /* От портретного планшета до ландшафтного экрана и настольных дисплеев */
  @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {

  }

  /* Большой дисплей */
  @media (min-width: 1200px) {

  }

  @media (min-width: 768px) {

  }
```

Внутри пишем класс например:

**общий класс:**

```
div{border: siolid 1px red; width:200px;}
```

**Этот же класс для расширения не более 767px:**

```
@media (max-width: 767px) { 
    div{width:100px;}
}
```

Меняем масштаб окна и смотрим